# Cleanflight : 4 first channels not working and "Failed to open serial port"

Tags: quadcopter, serial

I just finished assembling my new 250 quad which is equipped with an [SP F3 Flight controller](http://www.banggood.com/Upgrade-NAZE32-F3-Flight-Controller-Acro-6-DOF-Deluxe-10-DOF-for-Multirotor-Racing-p-1010232.html?rmmds=search).
I think that I kinda bricked my FC in the first 10 minutes of configuring it:

I first plugged it in, installed a few drivers and opened cleanflight
Cleanflight recognized it, no problem for now.
I then tried to test the RX channels and discovered that apart from the 4 AUX channels, none of them worked, I swapped the plugs on the transmitter and saw that the RX was OK, it's the FC that didn't show anything on the first 4 channels
After reading some stuff about upgrading the firmware I did something completely wrong, I followed the first 10 seconds of this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbCWg1605ag), using baseflight... though my board isn't baseflight it's cleanflight, and I did the mistake of clicking the "Flash firmware" button which then made it impossible to use it and flash it.

After some trial and error I finally had a problem where cleanflight tells me that it cannot flash the firmware on it because "Failed to open serial port"
I used Process Explorer to check if any program was using and holding the COM3 port but no
No Program was using it.
Thank you for reading this very long and probably stupid question, do you have anything that I can try?

Comment: Welcome to this site. Congratulations on solving your problem. However, please do not edit the solution into the question. As such, your question will never have an answer and will linger on forever. Instead, post your findings and what worked for you in an answer. (yes, an answer to your own question is perfectly fine here and actually encouraged) Then accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The com issue has been fixed by uninstalling all serial->COM drivers and programs that could've been interfering?? Dunno, some more Windows 10 magic I guess, but now remains he issue of the 4 first channels not working

I then installed the latest cleanflight firmware by following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVl1OHUouDQ), flashed without any problem.

It indeed fixed the channel issue and all I had to do next was to change the PID settings and reversed the yaw (I installed CCW motors where there should be CW) using "set yaw_direction = -1" on the CLI

It's now fully functional